# What are the criteria for deciding which sports to include in the Olympic curriculum?

Tags: olympics

I am surprised that squash has never been adopted, and I am wondering what the criteria are for deciding what to include.

There also seems to be an absence of sports which can be played by older people, such as lawn bowls. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44353/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-what-are-the-criteria-for-deciding-which-sports-to).

Comment: For what it's worth, Mark Todd, age 56, won a bronze medal at the 2012 Summer Olympics in Equestrian.

Comment: @ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ And similarly the British equestrian, Nick Skelton, aged 58, won gold in Rio. But these are unusual. And by "old" I mean really old. People in their 70s can play bowls!